# Sparql bound() not working

Tags: if-statement, bind, sparql

I am new to Sparql., I have a query to fetch a property from different subjects (say parent and parentG).

I have tried using

```
PREFIX ac: <http://ac.com/ns/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdf: <htp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT 
{
  ?item dcterms:isPartOf ?parent .
  ?parent dcterms:isPartOf ?parentG .
  ?item ac:scopedItem ?scopedItem .
}
WHERE 
{
  BIND ( <http://ac.com/content/Test1> as ?item )  .
  ?item dcterms:isPartOf ?parent .
  ?parent dcterms:isPartOf ?parentG .
  OPTIONAL 
  {
    OPTIONAL {?parent ac:htmlAdv ?advert .}
    BIND ( IF (BOUND (?advert), ?parent, ?parentG )  as ?scopedItem  ) .
  }
}
```

If the `?advert` is not bound from `?parent`, I want to go with `?parentG` and make it as `?scopedItem`. This is not working. We are using Sparql 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of scoping, SPARQL is evaluated from the bottom up so at the point where you have put the `BIND` statement neither `?parent` or `?parentG` are in scope so regardless of whether `?advert` is bound you will be returning nothing.

You need to move the `BIND` statement out one level in your query and then it should work correctly:

```
PREFIX ac: <http://ac.com/ns/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdf: <htp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT 
{
  ?item dcterms:isPartOf ?parent .
  ?parent dcterms:isPartOf ?parentG .
  ?item ac:scopedItem ?scopedItem .
}
WHERE 
{
  BIND ( <http://ac.com/content/Test1> as ?item )  .
  ?item dcterms:isPartOf ?parent .
  ?parent dcterms:isPartOf ?parentG .
  OPTIONAL 
  {
    ?parent ac:htmlAdv ?advert .
  }
  BIND ( IF (BOUND (?advert), ?parent, ?parentG )  as ?scopedItem  ) .
}
```

Note this also makes the use of two `OPTIONAL` clauses unnecessary

Comment: Thanks Rob., That was timely and helpful.. I got that working for my requirement.